# LM7805CV output voltage drop to 2.5v after connecting load

Tags: power-supply, transformer, lm78xx

I've made a simple linear power supply for micro-controller with a transformer and LM7805CV as seen in the picture.

LM7805CV input voltage is 35V and output without load is 5V but after connecting a minimum load like an LED with 1K resistor output voltage drop to 2.5V.

I've checked regulator input voltage and it's steady without any change but regulator input-output voltage increase to 32V which I think is the main reason for dropping voltage.

Transformer = 2x24V Center Tapped

[image]

Comment: Try half wave rectifier if you don't have non-center tapped transformer ! Just remove diode D2

Comment: You're certainly pushing the limit on all your components needlessly as @oceanp mentions. A 24V RMS transformer has a 34V peak output (\$V_p = V_{rms} \times \sqrt{2}\$). Your input cap is rated for abs. max 35V, as is your regulator. Not good operating conditions, especially as the voltage may be higher if the transformer input is higher than rated.

Comment: @sDev  can you confirm that you are using the TO220 version of the regulator (plastic block with three inline leads at one end and a bit of heatsink poking out the other)

Comment: @Raj I need 24VDC for ultrasonic sensor and fan that's why I used full wave rectifier. The 5v is using to feed ATmega 328 micro.

Comment: Then use two rectifiers, one for sensor (for this use full wave rectifier ) and one for controller (for this half wave rectifier )@sDev. Still u can use same  transformers for this

Comment: @Tom Carpenter I'm sure input voltage doesn't change but if you think increasing cap voltage can help this situation I can change that to higher voltage. As I stated in comment the 5v only using for ATmega 328 so I think hardly it reach more that 100mA.

Comment: @oceanp Yes I'm using TO220 version with heat sink attached to it.

Comment: Your voltage is too high, but there almost surely is another problem with your circuit. Maybe if you supplied a photo, and PCB layout it might be clearer.

Comment: You *could* use an LM317 (in a TO-220 package with a heatsink attached) to drop the input voltage to the 7805 to, say 10 V. That way you have two devices sharing the dissipation of the waste energy as heat.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany I don't have PCB yet but I did on pref board and bread board with same result. If picture from pref board or bread board helps let me know.

Comment: @Andrew Morton I've some LM317T in my stash so I'm going to check to see if that helps.

Comment: @sDev yes a clear picture might help

Comment: @sDev In the [datasheet](http://datasheet.octopart.com/L7805CV-STMicroelectronics-datasheet-7264666.pdf) you linked to, there are circuits for use with a high input voltage (by using a transistor pre-regulator) on pages 31 and 32.

Comment: @Andrew Morton Your proposal for using LM317 works, It seems LM7805 datasheet needs some modification in maximum rating, LM7805CV is not able to handle 35v input with load, after using LM317 to drop input voltage to 17v,fwstart working without problem. Guys, I thank all of you for your time and instant response you were all right about input voltage. Dear Andrew Morton Would you please post your comment as answer and if possible provide me more information about page 31 and 32(type of transistor / zener / resistor) so I can decide better on using LM317 or transistor pre-regulator?

Comment: Before you go the double linear regulator route can I suggest you look at this http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2575.pdf.  High efficiency which gives low power dissipation.

Comment: @Royc Thank you for suggestion , In the end I did change linear regulators with LM2576-5.0 because LM317 getting hot very fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

35V is the Absolute Maximum the device can cope with and should not be considered an operating voltage. The recommended max input for the 7805 is actually 25V (https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LM7805.pdf) and even that is going to generate a lot of heat compared to an input of say 8 to 10V.
At 35V in the 7805 will generate 4mA x 30V = 120 mW of heat which I would not expect to heat up enough to trigger the thermal shutdown even with no heat sink but maybe...
You can greatly reduce the heat generated in the regulator by reducing the input voltage (minimum input is about 2 or 3V above the output voltage).  You should still use a good heat sink if you want to draw more than a few mA.
It's normally recommended that the caps are connected close to the regulator to ensure stability. Not usually a problem with +ve regulators but maybe it's oscillating.

Comment: Thank you for recommendation I'm going to increase C3 to 10/100 nf as @oceanp stated and bring it closer to regulator if possible then if problem persist using full wave bridge on half of transformer. I'll post updates here.

Comment: Datasheet you've refereed to is different from one I'm using: http://datasheet.octopart.com/L7805CV-STMicroelectronics-datasheet-7264666.pdf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50312/discussion-between-raj-and-oceanp).

Comment: Full wave bridge across half the transformer will give you the same output voltage.

Comment: I'm confirming using full wave bridge on half of transformer doesn't change input voltage and problem persist also increasing C3 to 10 or 100nf doesn't change anything at all.

Comment: @RoyC Oops yes full wave bridge across 1/2 the xfrmr is obviously the same ivoltage (less 1 diode drop). My mistake, was very late here at the time haha. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Your input voltage to the regulator is way too high. You are generating V*I Watts in the regulator which is 30*your load current. These parts have a thermal protection circuit which will shut them down to protect themselves. You will probably find the part is getting hot.

You should be aiming for a voltage input to the regulator in the 10V region. To limit the power dissipation in the regulator aim for the lower end of the input voltage range rather than the higher.

If your thermal management is good it could be a stability problem  consider increasing C3 to 10n and make sure it is right across the regulator output also add another small capacitor (30n) straight across the regulator input. .

If you really need to create 5V from such a high input voltage consider using a Buck switching regulator.

Comment: While very true and worth considering, I'm not sure this is the entire the problem here - a 1k resistor on the output is at most a 5mA load, which equates to 150mW dissipation in the regulator and shouldn't cause an issue ([datasheet](http://datasheet.octopart.com/L7805CV-STMicroelectronics-datasheet-7264666.pdf) shows 100mA for 32V input @ 150*C at the limit) .

Comment: @oceanp Do you think taking around 50-100 mA current from 7805 can cause heat or problem for the regulator? Main part of system using 24v so I had to using 24v transformer 5v output only using to feed ATmega 328

Comment: @sDev if you try to pull 100mA with a 35V input, that is \$(35V-5V)\times0.1A=3W\$. That sucker is going to get hot as hell.

Comment: Hotter than hell is an understatement a TO220 without an extra heatsink is about 50C/Watt this is going to be 150C above ambient.

Comment: @Tom Carpenter Good point but currently voltage drop appear after 5mA draw without any heat sign on regulator.

Comment: @sDev can you measure the AC voltage across the output of the regulator when the DC output drops to 2.5V on reflection that number is suspicious.

Comment: @oceanp Do you mean DC voltage in regulator output? Regulator output also drop but still higher around 0.7v which is 3.2v before 1k resistor and 2.5v after resistor.

Comment: @sDev No I am looking for oscillation or instability in the regulator this will show up as an AC voltage on the output of the regulator. Just put ypur meter on AC volts and put it on the output.

Comment: @RoyC I've read 0VAC on regulator output after voltage drop.